# What is new about the CV in careers that makes it better than those on other job sites?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

Is it just me or does the CV section just seem to be more ho-hum kind of stuff?  Given the emphasis on Smart and Gets Things Done, I would have hoped for something that would give some better indications of this.  What is there or what could be added that would differentiate the CV from other job sites?

Comment: Do the other sites have ponies?

Comment: Why, yes, they do: http://www.horseback.com/jobs.html

Comment: Good answer ;-p

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see a place where we can post code samples.  Looking at a codes samples from prospective employees can be very valuable.  Being able to do this early on in the process of identifying prospects can save a lot of time.  Likewise, providing code samples can demonstrate your abilities in ways that your employment history and education can't.

Comment: Supposedly your careers profile will link directly to your SO profile so employers can see the code samples you posted there.

Comment: I'd rather that I have a place to show the code I want to highlight. Code provided in an answer isn't always (often) production quality -- nor does it need to be IMO

Comment: You could link to the open source projects you have worked on instead...
If I was an employer I'd be more interested in code that is "out there in production use" than something cooked up to look good on a CV.